# Comparar nombres de columnas de varios data frames

Tags: r

Tengo varios ficheros y quiero ver si todos tienen la misma dimensión y mismo nombre de columna.

Para abrir todos los ficheros:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

list.files(pattern = "*.*")  %>% lapply(read_excel) -> lista
```

Supongamos que son tres:

```
a <- iris[1:10,]
b <- iris[1:11,]
c <- iris[1:16,1:4]

lista <- list(a,b,c)
```

Para ver la dimensión:

```
for (i in 1:length(lista)) { print(dim(lista[[i]])) }
```

Para ver si todos tienen el mismo nombre de columnas (y poder ver estos nombres) había pensado ponerlos en un df. Algo por el estilo a esto, en un bucle:

```
colnames(lista[[1]]) == colnames(lista[[2]])

data.frame( colnames(lista[[1]]), colnames(lista[[2]]) )
```

pero si tienen dimensiones diferentes no puedo hacerlo.

¿Alguna solución?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La comparaciones son siempre entre dos elementos, en este caso al tener más elementos a comparar, lo que puedes hacer es generar previamente las combinaciones de 2 dos elementos de un conjunto de 3 o más.

```
combinaciones <- combn(length(lista), 2)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    2
[2,]    2    3    3
```

En este caso, cada columna, te da una posible combinación de dos índices de la lista para comparar, resta simplemente iterar y compara diferencias:

```
sapply(1:dim(combinaciones)[2],
       function(x) {
         i <- combinaciones[,x]
         dif <- setdiff(colnames(lista[[i[1]]]), colnames(lista[[i[2]]]))
         if (length(dif) == 0) 
            dif <- "Sin diferencias"
         return(paste('Lista', i[1], "vs lista", i[2], ":", dif))
       })

[1] "Lista 1 vs lista 2 : Sin diferencias"
[2] "Lista 1 vs lista 3 : Species"        
[3] "Lista 2 vs lista 3 : Species"
```